# How to deal with proxy restriction problems when using a search API like Algolia?

Tags: laravel, proxy, algolia

I am currently building an app using **Laravel 5**, I also have decided to integrate the **Algolia search API** for easy, quick and effective searches.
I am using the **search API** for the posts of my app. The problem is that when under an internet connection that is restricted through **proxy** the **API won't respond** throwing a "`Host unreachable: could not resolve host`" exception. Also, as the API "listens" for any changes in the searched model, the same exception will be triggered when trying to alter the searched model in any way, resulting in an unpleasant experience for users that browse behind a proxy. How do you, more experienced would deal with such problem?

Comment: Your host must be able to access the network, which is currently not the case according to the message. You should try to solve that issue.
Could you try to to `ping google.fr` from inside your host to see if that resolves? What environment are you working in?

Comment: Apparently, the pinging works just fine, all packages are received. It's hosted on an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Also, the problem appears only when accessing the website through a proxy.

Comment: So you have a hostile proxy that denies your application access to things it require. Can you remove the proxy? Reconfigure it? Summon the network guys to change it?

Comment: I live in a dorm right now, and these are the rules around, I pretty much don't have an option.

Comment: Anyways, so a proxy isn't supposed to block everything like this, right? I only care about the well-being of the app, so if the problem comes from this proxy, then there is nothing to worry about.